What are cross origin writes/reads?
The MDN page categorizes cross-origin access into 3 categories:


Cross-origin writes are typically allowed. Examples are links, redirects, and form submissions. Some HTTP requests require preflight.
Cross-origin embedding is typically allowed. (Examples are listed below.)
Cross-origin reads are typically disallowed, but read access is often leaked by embedding. For example, you can read the dimensions of an embedded image, the actions of an embedded script, or the availability of an embedded resource.


And these are some examples of these three categories.
But I'm quite confused. Why links and redirects are considered as "writes"? What do they write?

"Writes": any request that can result in changes to server-side state (like logging, processing, or analytics) or side effects on the server.

I think the terminology is poor. The important distinction is whether the operation returns data to the same script that the request was made from. Links, redirects, and form submissions load the response in a new page. They may make changes at the server, but they don't return anything that can be read.
